# Why does a CP-1252 ellipsis show up as u with ring above (ů) on some browsers

Tags: browser, latin1, windows-1252, cp1251

For some reason, on some browsers, a CP-1252 ellipsis (0x85) is showing up as ů.  I believe the server is claiming the page will be in UTF-8 (don't ask me why a UTF-8 server is serving CP-1252, that is out of scope).  I would understand throwing a warning because it isn't valid UTF-8.  I would understand it showing up as the Latin1 character [U+0085 NEXT LINE (NEL)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm). But I can't for the life of me figure out why it displays as [U+016F LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/16f/index.htm).

This is what I am seeing:

[image]

And here is a `hexdump -C` of the file

```
00000000  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
*
00000030  78 85 3c 2f 69 3e 0d 0a                           |x.</i>..|
00000038
```

Comment: The only way this should happen is if the browser is ignoring the page's reported charset and using a different charset instead, such as a user-specified override. But I don't know which charset(s) would interpret 0x85 as U+016F. None of the CP-12xx/Windows-12xx charsets do, 0x85 is U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS. And none of the ISO-8859-x even support 0x85 at all.

Comment: I found a charset that interprets 0x85 as U+016F: [CP852](http://www.kreativekorp.com/charset/encoding.php?name=CP852) (DOS Latin-2), not to be confused with [ISO-8859-2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) (ISO Latin-2).

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, it seems odd that a normally configured browser is treating some text as DOS Latin-2, but at least that makes more sense than the "it's magic" I was coming up with.  I will do some more tests to see if I can duplicate with different characters.

Answer (score 1):

Flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. Once upon time I have written a small `.bat` script that shows mappings of (most known) OEM and ANSI code pages to Unicode table and vice versa. Here's a particular result for `0x85` code:

```
==> alts.bat 0x85
CP/ACP  Hex  Codepoint  #Description   :show8bit 133 <--> 0x85)
------  ---  ---------  ------------------------
CP1250  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1251  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1252  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1253  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1254  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1255  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1256  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1257  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1258  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP437   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP737   0x85    0x0396  #GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ZETA
CP775   0x85    0x0123  #LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH CEDILLA
CP850   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP852   0x85    0x016f  #LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE
CP855   0x85    0x0401  #CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IO
CP857   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP860   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP861   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP862   0x85    0x05d5  #HEBREW LETTER VAV
CP863   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP864   0x85    0x2500  #FORMS LIGHT HORIZONTAL
CP865   0x85    0x00e0  #LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
CP866   0x85    0x0415  #CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IE
CP869   0x85            #UNDEFINED
CP874   0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP932   0x85            #DBCS LEAD BYTE
CP936   0x85            #DBCS LEAD BYTE
CP949   0x85            #DBCS LEAD BYTE
CP950   0x85            #DBCS LEAD BYTE

==>
```

and vice versa for `0x2026` codepoint (sorry for bad output columns shift in case of non-windows CP lines):

```
==> alts.bat 0x2026
CP/ACP  Hex  Codepoint  #Description   :show16bit 8230 <--> 0x2026
------  ---  ---------  -------------------------
CP1250  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1251  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1252  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1253  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1254  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1255  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1256  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1257  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP1258  0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP874   0x85    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP932   0x8163  0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP936   0xA1AD  0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP949   0xA1A6  0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
CP950   0xA14B  0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
macCYRILLIC_CP  0xC9    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
macGREEK_CP     0xC9    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
macICELAND_CP   0xC9    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
macLATIN2_CP    0xC9    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
macROMAN_CP     0xC9    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
macTURKISH_CP   0xC9    0x2026  #HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS

==>
```

Further reading: [Encodings and Code Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688114)